# Calling sqlplus in Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlplus

I have a batch script where I am calling sqlplus command as shown below. Is there a way, the password can be encrypted? When I run the script, the password is sent via clear text. I am looking for any options available.

sqlplus user/pass@local_SID

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't sqlplus just an Oracle client?  I would imagine there's some configuration options somewhere, governing whether you database connections are encrypted.  Have you tried the manual?  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: To hide your password, enter the CONNECT command in the form:
SQL> connect username@connect_identifier

You will be prompted to enter your password. From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/qstart.htm

Comment: Thank You, I am calling this via a script without manual intervention. When I call it using a batch file the password is in clear text. Please advise.

Comment: I gave you the page saying what you can do.

Comment: It will prompt me to enter the password base on the article you have provided, however I am running this as a scheduled job. So this will not serve the purpose.